# UIButtons setting tags

Tags: iphone

I have two buttons in my view. When I sent the tag value of one of them in Interface Builder they stop working. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: What do you mean they stop working? What error do you get? Can we see your method for the button press?

Comment: Post your code where you want to access the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the button in IB to an actual field? If not, then when you access the field it won't actually refer to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Set the button tag in code programmatically. then in the method which calls the button if(button.tag== [sender tag]){}

Answer (score 0):

Before posting please make sure that you describe your problem clearly.
Make sure all the wiring's are perfect,and look at your your console.
There will be some hints about what is exactly going wrong.